# Capture Gravity Forms fields values with javascript tag from third-party

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, gravityforms

The lead tracking system that we are using has provided us with the Javascript tag below, it is meant to pass the field values into the system:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var _lrx_profile = {
      "firstName": "PUT_FIRST_NAME_HERE",
      "lastName": "PUT_LAST_NAME_HERE",
      "email": "PUT_EMAIL_HERE"
    };
    _lrx_sendEvent('conversion', 14924, null, JSON.stringify(_lrx_profile));
</script>
```

I have implemented this tag with the gravity forms confirmation filter gform_confirmation and added it to the functions.php file as advised by the Gravity forms support, so this tag should load after a form is submitted and capture the name:

```
add_filter( 'gform_confirmation_48', 'custom_confirmation_message', 10, 4 );
function custom_confirmation_message( $confirmation, $form, $entry) {
        $name = rgar( $entry, '1.3' );
        $confirmation .= "<script type='text/javascript'>
   var _lrx_profile = {
      'firstName': $name
    };
    _lrx_sendEvent('conversion', XXXXXX, null, JSON.stringify(_lrx_profile));
</script>";
 
    return $confirmation;
}
```

Unfortunately nothing is being sent to the system, is there something wrong with the tag?

Comment: Did you mean to use XXXXXX?

Comment: that was just to hide the number

Comment: Got it.  You could try <script type=\"text/javascript\"> instead of <script type='text/javascript'>